# Using javascript map to expand a nested array into rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

How can I use `Array.prototype.map()` to turn this data structure:

```
[
  {text: "sometext", tags: ["t1", "t2", "t3"]},
  {text: "sometext2", tags: ["t4", "t5", "t6"]}
]
```

Into this data structure?

```
[
  {tag: "t1", text: "sometext"},
  {tag: "t2", text: "sometext"},
  {tag: "t3", text: "sometext"},
  {tag: "t4", text: "sometext2"},
  {tag: "t5", text: "sometext2"},
  {tag: "t6", text: "sometext2"}
]
```

Comment: where is your specific problem?

Comment: I won't use `.map()` for that situation, I believe `.reduce()` is better suited for that approach. If you show your efforts, maybe we can help you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take (upcoming) [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and map the inner arrays.

```js
var data = [{ text: "sometext", tags: ["t1", "t2", "t3"] }, { text: "sometext2", tags: ["t4", "t5", "t6"] }],
    result = data.flatMap(({ text, tags }) => tags.map(tag => ({ tag, text })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A result with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var data = [{ text: "sometext", tags: ["t1", "t2", "t3"] }, { text: "sometext2", tags: ["t4", "t5", "t6"] }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { text, tags }) => [...r, ...tags.map(tag => ({ tag, text }))], []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Array.map()` I will go with [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with a nested [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const input = [
  {text: "sometext", tags: ["t1", "t2", "t3"]},
  {text: "sometext2", tags: ["t4", "t5", "t6"]}
];

let res = input.reduce(
  (acc, {text, tags}) => (tags.forEach(tag => acc.push({tag, text})), acc),
  []
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think better will be use a reduce method for you case

```
    [
      { text: 'sometext', tags: ['t1', 't2', 't3'] },
      { text: 'sometext2', tags: ['t4', 't5', 't6'] }
    ].reduce(function(acc, item) {
      acc = acc.concat(item.tags.map((tag) => {
        return { tag: tag, text: item.text };
      }));

      return acc;
    }, []);
```